# Deleting data in a datagridview visual studios...?

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I'm connecting a data table into a datagridview. Once I run it,it's suppose to display a data table in the datagridview. (which it does) Only issue being I can't seem to away to delete the rows!

**last lines of code is for the complete button**
I couldn't find a way to do this if you are connecting a data table to datagridview. The table I am populating from is called JANITOR and I was able to connect to it just fine.

Here's my code. (I'm getting no errors but it does not work)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace LOGINPAGE
{
    public partial class JANITOR : Form
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda;
        SqlCommandBuilder scb;
        DataTable dt;


        public JANITOR()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void JANITOR_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'roomInfoDataSet3.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.roomInfoDataSet3.Table);

        }

        private void xButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void xButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void xButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mohamed\Desktop\LOGINPAGE\UserData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT Room_Number, Request_Type, Floor_ID FROM JANITOR", con);

            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }

        private void xButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Emergency Request Completed.");
        }

        private void xButton3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mohamed\Desktop\LOGINPAGE\UserData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");

             sda = new SqlDataAdapter("DELETE Room_Number, Request_Type, Floor_ID FROM JANITOR", con);

             dt = new DataTable();
        }

    }
}
```

[My Window.design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0mEa.png)

Comment: Please, clean up your code. Use descriptive variable and method names. Then, please describe what you expect to happen vs. what is actually happening.

Comment: Right now, nothing is happening. My connection to the database works and it loads into the datagridview but I am unable to delete rows in the table.

Comment: Probably worth reading up on the SQL DELETE syntax

Comment: You are trying to delete columns with that syntax.  You can only delete rows.  You aren't calling the code anyway.

Comment: Yeah, the rows is what I am trying to delete.

Comment: What's the code for deleting rows?

Comment: I tried using `this.RoomInfoDataSet3.RemoveCurrent();` but did not work.....